# Primefaces DataTable - Filtering [column not filtering]

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, filtering, primefaces

I am trying this [example 'DataTable - Filtering'](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf). Everything works except for the `Search all fields:` textbox that filters. when i enter characters to it it doesn't filter as in the example.

There is no errors or exceptions thrown. I don't undestand what `onkeyup="carsTable.filter()"` does in the code. can someone explain this ? and any idea why it fails to filter

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`carsTable` is the name of the datatable. Somehow its missing from the example, but the `p:dataTable` should have an attribute `widgetVar="carsTable"`. `onkeyup` is the event that is firedafter you released a key. It tells the `carsTable` to filter after you entered a new character.

So add the `widgetVar="carsTable"` attribute to `p:dataTable` and you are good to go.

If you have a look at the [PrimeFaces userguide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_2_2.pdf), you will find the correct example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the user guide. is there anyway i could use `filterMatchMode="startsWith"` to filter the text box in this section